# Problem solving with Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: means, variance

*The symmetric coin is tossed 1600 times. What is the probability that the head will be shown up more than 1200 times?*

I'm trying to solve this problem,but could not ot get correct answer.
Can you help me?

---

Attempt.
I should use Chebyshev inequality.

Using the formula $\mathbb{P}(|X-m|)>k)≤ var/k^2$

where m-mean, var - variance

Mean will equal = 800

Variance = 400

I put the numbers in it

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-800|>= 400)\le 400/400^2$$

But do not get the answer which is $\le 1/800$.

Comment: Here you have the absolute value which means that the bound gives you the probability to have more than 1200 heads or less than 400. By symmetry, you need to divide by two the probability since you only want the case with more than 1200 heads.

Comment: Can I use Markov's inequality for this problem?? I tried to solve but did not get the result

Comment: The result you get is $1/400$ which is twice the expected answer. Simply divide by $2$ to get $1/800$ according to my previous comment.

Comment: ok. I understood. But if i use Markovs inequality the result is 2/3....Can you explain why?

Comment: The Markov inequality is in general weaker than Chebyshev. In this case Markov only tells you that the probability will be less than $2/3$ while Chebyshev is way more precise saying less than $1/800$. Not that this is not a contradiction since $1/800 \leq 2/3$.